# Not being able to enter multiple comma seperated values in a column in database when sending a json request to the application

Tags: mysql, json, hibernate, spring-mvc

I know this is complex but please bear with me..........

I am building a Restful application. I have a specific requirement where there is a column named handle in my database. I need to store values like**(1,2,3,4)** in that column.

I am using spring mvc ,hibernate and eclipse as my IDE. I am also using PostMan Client.  I read about hibernate spatial data type and i decided to go with that however i am not being able to store the data in database.

I have been sending a json request containing data to my application through postman client in order to save those data to database .However i am not being able to do this?? What is the problem??..

This is my Json

```
{
    "operations": [
        {
            "operationType": 0,
            "objectType": 2,
            "data": {
                "idNum": 212632034672,
                "data": {
                    "radius": 80.11865321153431,
                    "strokeWidth": 5,
                    "stroke": "green"
                },
                "handle": {
                    "x": 223,
                    "y": 102
                },
 "parentId": 1
            }

        }
    ],
    "projectGuid": "ff8081814521f6ce014521f7756f0000"
}
```

I know the problem lies in handle part but i have not been able to solve it.......
Following is part of my model:-

```
@Column(name = "handle",columnDefinition="Geometry")
    @Type(type = "org.hibernate.spatial.GeometryType")
    private Point handle;
```

P.S. I am using org.hibernatespatial.mysql.MySQLSpatialInnoDBDialect in my jpaContext.xml file and i already have hibernate-spatial-4.0.jar in my class path already

Comment: Please provide the stack trace as well as your Spring configuration

Comment: Could be that the `HttpMessageConverter` is not able to deserialize `handle` to `Point`. But we can't know for sure without some stack traces or debug info.

Comment: @geoand  I am sorry for late reply..... I get http error that the request is syntatically incorrect when passing json in my POSTClient

Comment: @Bart I am sorry for late reply..... I get http error that the request is syntatically incorrect when passing json in my POSTClient

Comment: Then your problem is `HttpMessageConverter` related and probably not with Hibernate. You run the request and log with debug (or trace) level? They might you a clue what is going on.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion........hoping it will help me to figure it out